# Flush method in non-buffered streams

Tags: java, buffer, outputstream

There are some descendants of `OutputStream` which have inherited the `flush()` method.
For example `FileOutputStream` does have a flush() method even though it's not buffered. Does it mean that it gets buffered anyway within the same very stream? Otherwise, why should I call flush for a class which is not buffered?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Alex S in the below comment, this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849528/fileoutputstream-close-is-really-slow-when-writing-large-file).

Comment: Please search around or Google, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849528/fileoutputstream-close-is-really-slow-when-writing-large-file

Comment: tnx man you right I should have investigated more about it.