# Are there any performance benefits to leaving BufferedReader stream open?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

Before I ask my question, I am fully aware that leaving an input stream open can cause a memory leak, and therefore doing so is bad practice.

Consider the following preconditions:

- Only a single file is needed to be read
- The file in question is a text file which contains rows of data
- This file is quite large: 50MB or more
- The file is read many, many times during a test run

The reason I am asking is that in my test automation suite, the same file is required to be called over and over again to validate certain data fields.

In its current state, the data reader function opens a `BufferedReader` stream, reads/returns data, and then closes stream.

However, due to the file size and the number of times the file is read, I don't know if leaving the stream open would be beneficial. If I'm being honest, I don't know if the file size affects the opening of the stream at all.

So in summary, given the above listed preconditions, will leaving open a `BufferedReader` input stream improve overall performance? And is a memory leak still possible?

Comment: How do you intend to read the file again, from the beginning, with a reader that you've already used to read a previous version of the file until the end? What takes time is to read the 50 MB of data. Not opening and closing a reader. If the file is read-only, read the file once and for all, instead of reading it again and again.

Comment: From the beginning, with a reader class which has retained the input stream reference - I can't read the file just once, as it's part of a test Junit automation suite which dynamically calls the file depending upon the test being run

Comment: Then the obvious optimization is not to leave a buffered reader open. It's to read the file once, and store its content in memory. Note that, when opening a reder that reads from an InputStream, reading characters from the reader reads bytes from the underlying stream, and thus, once you've read all the characters, there is nothing to read anymore from the underlying input stream.

Comment: If you want to know how something might affect performance, [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: Ok, so the answer to my question is no. Can you make your comment a answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @Dukeling Sorry, this is for a client and i'm not on client site at the moment so cannot benchmark, but will do tomorrow. Its just something I've been thinking about over the weekend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have enough memory to do this, then you will probably get best performance by reading the entire file into a `StringBuilder`, turning it into a `String`, and then repeatedly reading from the `String` via a `StringReader`.

However, you may need 6 or more times as many bytes of (free) heap space as the size of the file.

- 2 x to allow for `byte` -> `char` expansion
- 3 x because of the way that a `StringBuilder` buffer expands as it grows.

You can save space by holding the file in memory as as bytes (not chars), and by reading into a `byte[]` of exactly the right size.  But then you need to repeat the bytes -> chars decoding each time you read from the `byte[]`.

You should benchmark the alternatives if you need ultimate performance.

And look at using `Buffer` to reduce copying.

---

Re your idea.  Keeping the `BufferedReader` open and using `mark` and `reset` would give you a small speedup compared with closing and reopening.  But the larger your file is, the smaller the speedup is in relative terms.  For a 50GB file, I suspect that the speedup would be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, not closing a stream could improve performance in theory as the object will not trigger garbage collection 
assuming you're not de-referencing the BufferedReader. Also, the undelying resources won't need to be sync'd.  See similar answer: [Performance hit opening and closing filehandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293309/performance-hit-opening-and-closing-filehandler?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, not closing you BufferedReader will result in [memory leak and you'll see heap increase](https://stackify.com/memory-leaks-java/).

I suggest as other's have in comments and answers to just read the file into a memory and use that. A 50MB file that isn't that much, plus the performance reading from a String once in memory will be much higher than re-reading a file.