# FileOutputstream.close() is not always writing bytes to file system?

Tags: java, android, filesystems, java-io

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849528/fileoutputstream-close-is-really-slow-when-writing-large-file#7849941) from @Peter Lawrey and especially this sentence :

> `close()` can ensure the file is actually written to disk (**or not depending on the OS**)

<sub>(emphasis is mine.)</sub>

I have 3 questions :

- Is it true that there is no guaranty that all the bytes will be available on disk after calling `close()` ?  (I guess it's true since it came from @Peter Lawrey)
- In general (i.e. valid on all OS), what is the best way to be sure that all bytes are effectively written to disk ? (I can imagine counting the bytes written to the stream, and *waiting until* `file.length() == byteCount` ... but is there a better approach ?)
- In particular, on **Android**, is it enough to call `fileOutputStream.close()` to be sure that all bytes are effectively written to the file system ?

Here is some code (ignoring exceptions, ... to keep it simple) to illustrate my post

```
    final InputStream instream = getInputStreamFromSomewhere();
    final FileOutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(someExistingFile);
    int l;
    final byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
    while ((l = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
            outstream.write(tmp, 0, l);
    }
    instream.close();
    //outputStream.flush(); //useless call since outputStream.flush() do nothing on FileOutputStream
    outputStream.close();
    //at this point : are all bytes written to disk ?
```

Comment: As Sagar Pilkwhal suggested (why did he remove his answer?) 1, 2, 3 The answer is: Use `flush();` before `close();`

Comment: As far as I know : flush() do noting in a FileOutputStream

Comment: i have edited my answer, added some more documentation link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
fileOutputstream.getFD().sync()
```

should do what you want. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html#sync()

Comment: Agreed. "You sync, you win".

Comment: 2022 this does not work anymore