# Does FileOutputStream.close() guarantee contents to be written to disk

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

[FileOutputStream.close is really slow when writing large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849528/fileoutputstream-close-is-really-slow-when-writing-large-file#7849941)

I found reference to my question in the above link and one of the bloggers (Black Joker) had opinion that close operation on the outputstream does not guarantee that the contents are written to disk. Is that a fair or true statement ?

Comment: Possible duplicate, with a good answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732760/4793951

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java, when I call OutputStream.close() do I always need to call OutputStream.flush() before?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732260/in-java-when-i-call-outputstream-close-do-i-always-need-to-call-outputstream)

Comment: flush does not write the data to disk. From what i have researched, it will just send the data to OS buffers. So when i call close, does it really write the contents to the disk or it will just close the outputstream for any further use.

Comment: @AmeyK I think that's up to the operating system, not up to Java.

Comment: Thanks Louis Wasserman